# Eslint resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolver

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I have an issue that all `.ts` files have this error on the first import line.

```
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/namespace
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/order
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/no-duplicates
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/extensions
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/default
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/no-named-as-default
Resolve error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolvereslintimport/no-named-as-default-member
```

My eslintrc.js I tried to install `yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript` but when I add it to my eslint it breaks everything and no linting is done.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    es2022: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:promise/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.d.ts'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
      },
      extends: [
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
      ],
    },
  ],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/'],
      },
    },
  },
 (`require('./tsconfig.build.json').exclude`)
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'dist'],
  rules: {

    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        ts: 'never',
        'd.ts': 'never',
      },
    ],

    'import/order': [
      'error',
      {
        groups: [
          'builtin',
          'external',
          'internal',
          'parent',
          'sibling',
          'index',
          'object',
          'type',
        ],
        'newlines-between': 'always',
        alphabetize: {
          order: 'asc',
        },
      },
    ],
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
  },
};
```